# close jframe while opening new one

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jframe, mouse-listeners

i try to open new frame which is named stage2 while closing the main frame. but when i put main.setVisible(false) there its said not an enclosing class and i put this listener on jpanel class which called by the mainframe. so its look like this..

```
class main extends JFrame()
{
   main()
     {
     }
   add(story2)
}

class story2 extends JPanel()
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {

                 new stage2(); 
                 main.this.setVisible(false);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `story2` is indeed not an inner class of `main`. You should use JComponent's **[getTopLevelAncestor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29)** to get a handle to the JFrame `story2` is in and then do what you want with the JFrame. Something like this:

```
((JFrame)this.getTopLevelAncestor()).dispose();
```

(If you won't be needing `main` JFrame any more, it is better to use **[`dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)** than just `setVisibke(false)`, in order to free resources and memory.)

The above code-sample is just a demonstration. In a production-ready app you should, of course, first check that the top-level ancestor can be cast to JFrame (or at least Window).